# T-SQL - Query distinct matches between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables with column names: ID, First Name, Last Name
The ID column on both tables are not related. I want to return all 3 fields from both tables, where the first names and last names match exactly 1 record on the other table.

Something like below:

[image: Expected]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a simple `join`?

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (select t1.*, count(*) over (partition by firstname, lastname) as cnt
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 join
     (select t2.*, count(*) over (partition by firstname, lastname) as cnt
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.firstname = t2.firstname and
        t1.lastname = t2.lastname and
        t1.cnt = 1 and t2.cnt = 1;
```

Comment: Not really, cause that would return all the matches. Tried, grouping & having count(ID) = 1, but then I wouldn't be able to get the IDs.

Comment: @NoobDev . . . That helps explain what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Table1 A
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 B ON A.FirstName = B.FirstName AND A.LastName = B.LastName;
```

Would this do the trick for you?